# How to read data from multiple database files?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, serilog, system.data.sqlite

My application uses Entity Framework Core, SQLite and Serilog to log to an SQLite database named Database.db. When Database.db reaches 10 MB Serilog creates a new database and renames the previous Database-someDate.db. I can't read from Database-someDate.db, only from Database.db.

How can I read from these files or force it to only use one file?

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    var connectionString =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqliteConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connectionString);
}
```

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name ="SqliteConnectionString"
         providerName="System.Data.Sqlite"
         connectionString="Data Source= ./Database.Db"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

NuGet packages:

[image]

Serilog config:

```
<appSettings>
    <!--serialog-->
    <add key="general:serilog:minimum-level" value="Verbose"/>

    <!--serilog sqlite-->
    <add key="sqlite:serilog:using:SQLite" value="Serilog.Sinks.SQLite"/>
    <add key="sqlite:serilog:write-to:SQLite.sqliteDbPath" value="Database.db"/>
    <add key="sqlite:serilog:write-to:SQLite.tableName" value="Logs"/>
    <add key="sqlite:serilog:write-to:SQLite.storeTimestampInUtc" value="false"/>
    <add key="sqlite:serilog:write-to:SQLite.autoCreateSqlTable" value="true"/>

</appSettings>
```

Comment: Neither SQLite nor EF Core generate new files every 10MB. What you posted can't be using EF Core either (at least not a supported version) because EF Core only runs on .NET Core which has no `app.config` or `web.config` files. Post code that actually replicates the problem and mention the actual .NET and package versions you use in the question itself

Comment: EF Core dropped support for .NET Framework with EF Core 5. System.Data.Sqlite itself was replaced by [Microsoft.Data.Sqlite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/?tabs=netcore-cli). Even in .NET Framework, you should be using the `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` package. Any problems found are fixed in the new package, not the legacy `System.Data.Sqlite`

Comment: _" And when my "Database.db" file reaches 10MB, the sqlite or ef core creates a new database file "Database.db""_ - I would expect this to be explicitly implemented _in your application_.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, i can use a app.config in my .net6 app using [ConfigurationManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/6.0.1?_src=template). I editing post, and send my nugget packages.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods unfortunately not, or I don't know how this can occurs.

Comment: @IsaevSemyon that's a compatibility class meant to ease migration of old applications. It's not meant to be used in new applications. What you posted doesn't write anything to any database anyway. Post code that actually replicates the problem.

Comment: Does your code use SQLite database partitioning perhaps? Or is there code that copies the database file based on size eg for backup purposes?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I changed the vendor name to "Microsoft.Data.Sqlite" but that didn't work. Now I tested the application - Database.db reaches 10036 KB and I see new "Database.db" and "Database20230807_043353.25.db" again. If you say that this should not be, but I do not implement it. What could be due to the fact that it implements some other mechanism? For example "serilog"?

Comment: That's the package name, not the vendor name. You're using different libraries, not just names. `For example "serilog"` are you using *Serilog*? Are you using SQLite as a Serilog sink?

Comment: Post code that actually reproduces the problem. You haven't posted any code that even writes to the database but you give hints that something unusual is going on, mentioning a legacy package here, Serilog there. We can't even guess what's going on because neither EF nor SQLite split databases.

Comment: It would  be a *lot* better if you reduced your code to the minimum that reproduces the problem. Start from the minimum (just a DbContext and code that adds rows), then add code little by little until you reproduce the problem. This will probably help you fix the problem too - whatever causes the problem will be in the last addition

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it is [repositry](https://github.com/semacool/MultipleFilesDb). I reduced to the minimum that reproduces the problem. Serilog.sink.sqlite to solve this problem.

Comment: The minimum is adding in the question itself that you refer to a database managed by Serilog. That's what creates new log database files periodically. Don't use the same SQLite database for logging *and* application data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found in [repository](https://github.com/saleem-mirza/serilog-sinks-sqlite/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.SQLite/LoggerConfigurationSQLiteExtensions.cs)
I decided to increase the size of the database, focusing on the size of my application

In appSettings:

```
    <!--serilog sqlite-->
    <add key="sqlite:serilog:using:SQLite" value="Serilog.Sinks.SQLite"/>
    <add key="sqlite:serilog:write-to:SQLite.sqliteDbPath" value="Database.db"/>
    <add key="sqlite:serilog:write-to:SQLite.tableName" value="Logs"/>
    <add key="sqlite:serilog:write-to:SQLite.storeTimestampInUtc" value="false"/>
    <add key="sqlite:serilog:write-to:SQLite.autoCreateSqlTable" value="true"/>

    <!--parameter responsible for the size of the database file (MB), maximum-10GB -->
    <add key="sqlite:serilog:write-to:SQLite.maxDatabaseSize" value="2048"/>

    <!--parameter responsible for the creating a new file-->
    <add key="sqlite:serilog:write-to:SQLite.rollOver" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the same SQLite file both for Serilog logging and application data. This is neither an SQLite nor an EF Core problem. The log database is configured and controlled by the Serilog sink.

If you use the [Serilog.Sinks.SQLite](https://github.com/saleem-mirza/serilog-sinks-sqlite) sink, the log database will be split when it reaches the default maximum size. Old files will get deleted based on a retention threshold too. [As the source code shows](https://github.com/saleem-mirza/serilog-sinks-sqlite/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.SQLite/LoggerConfigurationSQLiteExtensions.cs#L50) the default maximum log size is 10 MB.

You don't need to use .NET Framework configuration files either. Serilog works with the .NET Core configuration middleware already. You can use either `Serilog.AspNetCore` or `Serilog.Extensions.Hosting` and load settings with `.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)`.

In the [Serilog service sample](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-hosting/blob/dev/samples/SimpleServiceSample/Program.cs), Serilog is configured along with the host :

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddHostedService<PrintTimeService>())
            .UseSerilog((context, services, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.Console());
```

The settings are loaded from the same configuration used by the rest of the application. The sample's `appsettings.json` contains

```
﻿{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you can't get rid of such a mechanism, then tell me how you can solve the following case - I have to send all the logs via API to the server once a minute. If there is no Internet, then I store the logs until the Internet is available and all the logs are sent to the server.